# Como ajustar automaticamente uma JFrame ao tamanho de ecrã?

Tags: java, jframe

eu tenho um programa e quando executo em diferentes computadores a janela fica toda desmanchada e não se consegue ver os componentes que tem na Jframe, gostava de saber se há alguma maneira de a janela ser automaticamente ajustada ao ecrã desse tal computador de maneira a que ficassem os componentes no seu lugar

Comment: Vai depender de como está montado seu layout. É um pouco difícil responder sua pergunta sem saber exatamente como esta seu código. Dê uma olhada no link do comentario que eu deixei na resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Tenta fazer isso

```
Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  
Dimension tamTela = kit.getScreenSize();  

//Pega largura e altura da tela 
int larg = tamTela.width;  
int alt = tamTela.height;  

/* larg x 0.7; para ocupar 70% da tela por exemplo  */  
/* alt x 0.7;*/  

//Manda o JFrame utilizar suas dimensões  
setSize(larg,alt);
```

Comment: Ja entendi mas nao e isso que pretendo ate porque quero que o programa ocupe todo o ecra

Comment: O ecra não seria a tela inteira?

Comment: e para ocupar a tela  inteira o unico problema e que por exemplo nos ecras dos pcs da minha escola sao quadrados e a jframe fica formatada diferente e eu queria que fosse sempre igual(ajustada automaticamnete)

Comment: Há entendi, pensei que queria que fizesse ela ficar full automaticamente em qualquer tela. Pois esse código faz isso. Mas seu problema parece ser com os posicionamento dos componentes dentro dela né.

Comment: exacto por exemplo o meu monitor do portatil onde fiz o programa e maior do que o da escola por isso alguns componentes desaparecem, sabe alguma maneira de fazer o que desejo?

Comment: Vou ver se acho e te passo ok. Usei poucas vezes jframes.

Comment: poderia me mandar o site com essa informacao ?

Comment: Estou procurando, vai pesquisando ai por GridBagLayout, leia isso http://javafree.uol.com.br/topic-5792-Tudo-sobre-o-GridBagLayout.html

Comment: Deem uma olhada nisso: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html A solução é provavelmente uma composição de vários desses layout managers

Answer (score 1):

Coloque no initializeComponentes()

```
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    pegarResolucao();
```

e Cria essa função

```
private void pegarResolucao() {
        Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension dimensao = t.getScreenSize();
        this.setSize((dimensao.width + 5), (dimensao.height - 38));

 }
```