# Problema com posição e tamanho de componentes

Tags: java, swing, layout

Estou fazendo um programa usando o assistente, o famoso "clica e arrasta". Boa parte do projeto estou fazendo no meu computador, e uso o comando pra maximizar a tela no frame, e ajeito certinho os painels pra que tudo encaixe, mas quando continuo o projeto no computador do meu serviço por exemplo, o tamanho muda completamente e fica cortando como se não coubesse na tela.

[image: Essa é a tela que fica no computador do serviço]

[image: essa é a tela que fica no meu notebook]

Queria saber se tem alguma forma de padronizar isso, independente do computador, faça com que a tela abra em tela cheia e se encaixe conforme o desktop.

Comment: qual a IDE está usando pra montar as telas?

Comment: NetBeans IDE v8.2

Comment: Sim tem como padronizar,  forneça um **[mcve]**  para que seja possivel te ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

Se quer definir os tamanhos de forma relativa, de forma que as posições sejam respeitadas independente da tela, você precisa utilizar os [**gerenciadores de layouts**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Eles servem como organizadores de componentes na tela ou dentro de outros componentes na propria tela. Com isso, você sempre terá a mesma organização independente da resolução da tela do usuário que está executando a aplicação.

Quanto a manter o tamanho do `JFrame` relativo ao tamanho da tela do usuário, [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/39800/28595) há uma solução que pode funcionar.

Como você não apresentou um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), não dá para sugerir nada de específico para a tela apresentada, mas a solução com certeza é o uso de um ou mais gerenciadores.

Apenas para demonstrar o poder dos gerenciadores de layout, juntamente com a dica da resposta linkada, veja o exemplo abaixo onde fiz uma tela com proporçoes relativas a metade da minha tela, e mesmo redimensionando, os componentes náo se desorganizam, apenas a tabela se adapta graças ao `JScrollPane`.:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O assistente do netbeans pode parecer tentador, mas usá-lo sem conhecer a API swing e seu funcionamento vai te engessar nesta IDE e te prender a problemas como o que você enfrenta nesta pergunta. Sugiro que, antes de brincar de arrastar e soltar, aprenda o basico sobre swing e seus componentes, pois é essencial ter noção, de como criar telas e organizar componentes sem depender de IDEs, por mais que o construtor de telas do netbeans ou windowbuilder no eclipse facilitem bastante esse processo.

Answer (score -3):

Faça uma janela com menos pixels que quando aumentar o próprio windows corrige. mas se a janela for muito grande ele não pode fazer isso pra não perder informação.

Você usou o clica e arrasta pras opções do seu computador, mas você precisa fazer um padrão menor para que caiba em todas as telas possíveis. tente setar seu monitor na hora de clicar e arrastar pra 1024x768 por exemplo. é uma resolução ruim mas caberá em qualquer  computador. Depois que você voltar ao tamanho normal  a tela vai ficar melhor.

Mas o certo é não utilizar o clica e arrasta mesmo haha

Comment: Não existem definições percentuais no modo drag and drop?